# OpenCV and TBB error x64

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, tbb, opencv3.1

I have the following configuration:

- OpenCV 3.2.0-dev
- Windows 10.0.14393 AMD64
- CMake:                       3.7.1
- CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
- GCC MinGW 6.3.0
- Intel TBB 2017 Update 4

I'm trying to install OpenCV with TBB. I downloaded the Intel TBB 2017 Update 4 and set every path in the correct way.

[image]

I build (of course) the TBB library before to add it in the CMake, in this way:

```
mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=ia64
```

And I add the following path in the system variables:

```
C:\tbb-2017\include
C:\tbb-2017\build\windows_intel64_gcc_mingw6.3.0_release
```

But I have this error when I compile with CMake:

```
C:\opencv3\release>mingw32-make -j8
[  1%] Built target zlib[  1%] [  1%] [  1%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj[  1%]

Building CXX object modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx.objBuilding CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
[  4%] Built target libjpeg

[  6%] Built target libjasper
Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgcodecs_px.obj
[  6%] Built target opencv_perf_core_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
[  7%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_flann_pch_dephelp
In file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\core\opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
cIn file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/imgproc/src/precomp.hpp:50:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\imgproc\opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
oIn file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/ts/src/precomp.hpp:2:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\ts\opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
cmIn file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/videoio/src/precomp.hpp:48:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\videoio\opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
ocpcmoi[  7%] lmoBuilding CXX object modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
ppmaiiptlIn file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/imgcodecs/src/precomp.hpp:48:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\imgcodecs\opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
liiacalototanimit opoitninoe l nrtat metetirirenmomrainimtn nieatandteta.eret
mddei..dn

.a
tedmodules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
.mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
modules\imgproc\CMakeFiles\opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed

modules\ts\CMakeFiles\opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2216: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
modules\videoio\CMakeFiles\opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:8292: recipe for target 'modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
modules\imgcodecs\CMakeFiles\opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/ts/CMakeFiles/opencv_ts_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2867: recipe for target 'modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:7513: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:6906: recipe for target 'modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/imgcodecs/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:48:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\highgui\opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:8085: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/test/test_precomp.hpp:17:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\core\opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2360: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
In file included from C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/flann/src/precomp.hpp:23:0,
                 from C:\opencv3\release\modules\flann\opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
C:/opencv3/opencv-master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/private.hpp:63:23: fatal error: tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory
 #  include "tbb/tbb.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
modules\flann\CMakeFiles\opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2617: recipe for target 'modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/flann/CMakeFiles/opencv_flann_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

C:\opencv3\release>
```

Can you help me?

## Solution

I changed from CMake the ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS flag from ON to OFF and everythings worked...

Comment: CMake reported many times it can't find `tbb.h`, `tbb/tbb.h: No such file or directory #  include "tbb/tbb.h"`. Is the search path correctly set up?

Comment: of course. It is

Comment: Your `CMake` GUI showed `BUILD_TBB` not ticked?

Comment: is not ticked, yes.

Comment: You say you add two things in *"the system variables"*.... which system variables, where, how?

Comment: oh in windows system variables in the PATH section. This is not the problem

Comment: This is exactly the problem. The `PATH` only controls where Windows looks for executable programs. It does not control where a compiler looks for header (include) files at all. You need to add a `include_directories(XYZ)` into your CMakeLists.txt file where `XYZ` is the directory that contains `tbb/tbb.h`

Comment: Any luck with it now  ?

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: You haven't shown what you changed? Please show your complete `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: If you found an answer (it seems like you did) please put it ***as an answer*** and accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed from CMake the ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS flag from ON to OFF and everythings worked...